# Acceder a las propiedades de un arreglo para mostrarlas en la vista

Tags: javascript, angular

Estimadas(os),
Estoy experimentando con el uso de arrays en Angular y me he entrampado en un problema: Consumo una API que me devuelve un array anidado (contiene todos los datos y es en el que hago la búsqueda), este array lo puedo leer y mostrar las propiedades que desee en la vista. Luego quiero hacer una selección de items para capturar y mostrar solo los que me interesen, para esto uso un nuevo array ("mySel") que voy llenando cuando se producen una o más coincidencias con el término de búsqueda en el curso de la consulta. Cuando se produce una coincidencia capturo algunas propiedades desde el origen y con "push" las llevo a "mySel", este array lo copio al arreglo "indicsFound" y luego limpio o vacío "mySel" para continuar recorriendo el array de datos hasta terminar, finalmente muestro en consola el array "indicsFound" en que he guardado todas las coincidencias. Hasta aquí todo funciona bien, el problema aparece al querer acceder a las propiedades de los items que contiene "indicsFound" para imprimirlas en la vista.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar para salir de esto

[image: Mi controlador]

[image: ...Cuando encuentro una coincidencia:]

[image: Termina el método de búsqueda y tengo "indicsFound" con todas las coincidencias encontradas]

[image: En consola puedo ver que todo resultó bien...]

[image: Pero al querer acceder a sus propiedades en la vista...]

[image: Solo obtengo esto... ninguna propiedad!! aunque si "lee" que existen dos items]

---

Francisco Núñez, gracias por tu ayuda!

La expresión, en la interpolación desde la vista, para acceder a las propiedades de mi array "indicsFound" es como sigue:

```
  <li *ngFor = "let items of indicsFound">
    <h4>
      {‌{items[0]['TemaGeneral']}}
    </h4>
 </li>
```

Comment: te recomiendo que lo que es codigo javascript lo pegues como codigo no uses imagenes mas que para poder los resultados de la consola y trata de simplificar todo en un ejemplo funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que muestras aquí:

[image: En consola puedo ver que todo resultó bien...]

esto debería de tirarte el ouput del texto:

```
console.log(this.indicsFound[0][0]['TemaGeneral']);
```

me comentas; pero en serio necesitas pegar el código y un ejemplo del objeto, para poder manipularlo y darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: De acuerdo Francisco, gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, disculpas a todas(os) por las imágenes, lo tendré en cuenta y corregiré para una próxima (solo para no recargar este tema). La expresión en el console.log que me propones sí funciona... el tema es cómo reproduzco esto en la interpolación desde la vista.El intento con: " *ngFor = "let items of indicsFound"... {{items[0][0]['TemaGeneral']}}" me devuelve un error: ("Cannot read property 'TemaGeneral' of undefined")

Comment: @Sebastián bueno no te puedo responder esa pregunta por que no veo el código que hace eso... o un error referente a esa `interpolacion` lo que si se es que si tienes el html en texto plano en una variable; tienes que iterrar ese texto y replazarlo con el valor que desea del objeto.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Franscisco, me permitió encontrar la solución: la expresión para la interpolación en la vista es "{{items[0]['TemaGeneral']}}"

Comment: @Sebastián que bueno marca como resuelta la pregunta, que tengas buen dia.